# NSButton Text Drawing

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawrect, nsbutton

I am trying to re-draw the text of my NSButton so that it is positioned different. E.g. not centered but offset to be sat lower.

I have my button in my xib with custom class set and text set etc. Lets say the text I set in the xib is 'Test'.

Now in my subclass, I use the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    
    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [NSFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:12.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                    nil];
    
    NSRect rect;
    rect.size = [[self title] sizeWithAttributes:attributesDict];
    rect.origin.x = roundf( NSMidX([self bounds]) - rect.size.width / 2 );
    rect.origin.y = roundf( NSMidY([self bounds]) - rect.size.height / 4 );
    [[self title] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributesDict];
}
```

This sort of works, but has one big issue. This code takes the string as expected and gives it all the correct formatting and positioned just where I want it.

However, it merely adds a second string. So After this has run I have a button with the original 'Test' text I made in the xib, all centered just a typical unmodified NSButton and then my second offset string beneath it.

I don't want two strings in one button. How can I stop this duplication but also achieve having an offset title?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: The answer below is aimed at UIButton, not NSButton. Probably some of it will be valid, probably not everything...**

I keep getting beaten for advocating not to subclass UIButton, but I'll do it again. The reason is: you do not know what behavior you'll get, there is just no guarantee. You think you set the type to "custom"? How? There's no writeable property, and there is no init-method that you could use for that either.

Apperently it works, and Apple does so in an example, but I'll keep repeating: Just because it works now in OS a.b, doesn't mean it will work in OS a.b.1. Though it probably (!) will.

Anyway, the reason you see the string now doubled up is that the label is still part of the view hierarchy. You can do one of the following: remove it from its super view, set it's color to clear, set its text to nil, ...

Whatever you do, if you want to make sure that your custom drawRect: method keeps working, you probably need to keep your title around.

I'd rather set the attributedTitle of the button to get the desired result.

And if you feel you need to subclass, maybe try to overwrite layoutSubviews as well to adjust the position of the label, but again, be prepared to get surprised *at anytime*.

Comment: Don't worry I know the risks! Note I was referencing `NSButton`, not `UIButton`. Two different kettles of fish. Regardless, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Oops, sorry :) I guess some of it might still be valid. :)